# Default move constructor

Tags: c++, gcc4.8

I have a database class and the explicit constructor tries to connect to the database based on flags passed in, if it fails then it throws. This is not desired (the database may not of been created by another app) so I added a blank constructor and default move constructors. In a utility class I wait until the database is created and move a new one in.

In unit tests I see that the `database_utils::connected()` returns false before I move and true after the move. However if I call a function that uses the database I get a `library routine called out of sequence` error. This would suggest I haven't opened the database or a malformed select statement but the constructors and destructor are called in the correct order and I have unit tests for the database itself where it creates the database, populates it and the select statement works.

So my question: **Is the default move actually moving it or not? If not what do I need to do to obtain the expected behaviour?**

Sample code:

```
class database
{
    database() : connected_(false), database_(nullptr) { }
    database(/* params */) : connected_(false), database_(nullptr) { 
        /* attempt connection, throw on fail */
        connected_ = true;
    }
    database(database& other) = default;
    database(database&& other) = default;
    database& operator=(database&& other) = default;
    ~database() { /* clean up */ }
    operator bool() const { return connected_; }

    bool connected_;
    sqlite3* database_;
};

class database_utils
{
    database_utils() : db_() { }
    void connect() {
        db_ = std::move(database(/*params*/));
    }
    bool connected() { return db_; }
    void example_select(/* params */) {
        /* use db_ */
    }
    database db_;
};
```

Comment: If you would like to verify that your move constructor is getting invoked, put a debugging statement in it, and see if it comes out. You are aware, of course, that there's nothing in the default constructor that will make it null out the moved-from object's pointers, like `database_`, which certainly looks like a bug. You need to write your own move constructor, that does the right thing.

Comment: [OT]: copy constructor take its arg by const reference.

Comment: You probably want the move constructor to reset pointer of moved to avoid double clean up.

Comment: Read about [the implicitly defined move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-defined_move_constructor).

Comment: @Jarod42 Only the database object being moved in should have `database_` set as the object being moved out is `nullptr` and should be destructed straight away?

Comment: What is `database_` ? If it is a pointer, moving it is just a copy so you may have trouble, if it is a `std::unique_ptr`, it would be actually be moved, so that part should be ok. If you provide a minimal sample, it would be easier to help, as we don't have to guess.

Comment: @Jarod42 `database_` is pointer to a a database object - in this case a sqlite3 handle. I will post a cut down test, but the actual failing tests have fixtures and need several objects which are not listed here (loggers, etc.) so it may not compile directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default move constructor do move everything.

However `database_` is pointer. Pointer move is actually copy.

Then in the destructor, `database_` will be deleted.

Because both "old" and "new" object's `database_` points to same memory location, "new" object will be in non stable state, since `database_` will point into hyperspace.

If you can change `database_` to be smart pointer, the default move constructor will work just well.

Alternatively, make your own move constructor that move everything and set `database_` to `nullptr` and `connected_` to `false`.

Comment: I would of thought a pointer move would be swap, so if a->0x0000 and b->0x1234 would become a->0x1234 and b->0x0000.

Comment: no, this is incorrect. if you do your own move constructor, swap would be great, but default move constructor will not do swap.